# Is PiCAST supposed to work like ChromeCast? If not, then which project would?

Tags: audio, streaming-video, streaming, shairplay, chromecast

I'm looking for a program that will simulate ChromeCast on my Pi 3. I successfully installed PiCAST but I'm not seeing a new device where I can stream to on chrome on my mac or on android.
Is PiCAST supposed to simulate ChromeCast or is it just a program that looks like ChromeCast but can only be controlled by sending the to-be-streamed media within the URL?
If the latter is true, then is there another program that I can use to simulate ChromeCast on Pi 3 pretty much like shairpoint-sync simulates AirPlay?

Answer (score 2):

I am using simple HTTP protocol to connect to my RPi. So, if you can have the IP of your PI, it will work.

On RPi, am running this python service. I am planning to add more security to this later. But for now, in a mini setup, this works. I have even developed an android application around it(find it in my blog series for YOUPICAST).

```
from flask import Flask       
import os
from threading import Thread

app=Flask(__name__)

def run(cmdStr):
os.system(cmdStr)

@app.route('/yt/')
def PlayNow(url):
    pid = os.system('$(pidof omxplayer)')
    if pid > 0:
        os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    modUrl = 'https://youtube.com/watch?v='+url
    cmdStr = 'omxplayer -o hdmi `youtube-dl -g -f 18 %s` --blank' % (modUrl)
    threads = Thread(target=run,args=(cmdStr,))
    threads.daemon = True
    threads.start()
    return 'Added : Url - ' + url

@app.route('/kill')
def Kill():
    pid = os.system('$(pidof omxplayer)')
    if pid > 0:
         os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    return 'Killed'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please note that answers on the Stackexchange should stand on their own. That means that they should not just promote your blog but provide a real answer here that has value without following an external link.

Comment: ... in fact, this is how we handle it now: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Comment: @Ghanima let me know if this looks like a decent answer to the question. Since the user asked for alternatives, I am giving it to him or her.

Comment: Hello Rajesh, thanks for updating the answer. Please note that it is not my place to value the decency (all users could and should do that via voting) but it is part of moderation to point out the rules of the site (such as the link-only-ness of answers).

Answer (score 0):

PiCAST uses a completely custom protocol incompatible with devices which actually support Google Chromecast.

Furthermore , just like Apple Google is always modifying the protocol which has completely broken projects like leapcast already. **If your device supports MiraCast , try using the "[Miraclecast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast)" project** , it used to work on Raspberries and is based on a purportedly vendor-neutral standard.